# Tampura vs 4-4 Tabla Playing during Bansuri Practice

Tags: practice, rhythm, indian-classical, bansuri

So far, I thought one should play Tampura when practicing Bansuri. The Tampura must be on `Pa` and on the same scale as the Bansuri.

Now this video says we must use 4-4 Tabla (which, of course can be downloaded as an app)

But I am really confused.

When do we play Tampura in the background, and when do we play 4-4 Tabla in the background?

#### Further Info

The following video introduces Rhythm. As soon as he says turn on 4-4 Tabla I get lost

Please clarify my above questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanpura plays the base shruti continuously in the background (with Sa, bottom Sa, and Pa). This develops the reference for the rest of the notes. If you change the Tanpura settings, the same set of fingering can surprisingly bring the feeling of an entirely different raga!

On the other hand, Tabla provides the rhythm. Tabla is also tuned to the shruti provided by Tanpura, for which, one setting is provided in the electronic and software Tabla. The shruti of a physical (actual) Tabla is adjusted by delicately adjusting the tensions on its leather strings on the sides.

In the very beginning, it's easy to add the Tanpura, as it only plays itself, filling up the musical space with a soothing background. When it's time to use the rhythm, Tabla can be added.